# how to show sensor status with grafana and influxdb?

Tags: grafana, influxdb, grafana-templating

I have grafana to display my sensors data and influxdb to store the data tha come from these sensors.
Is it possible to show the status of my sensor on grafana for example i can add a field in influxdb with on or off how to display only on with a green color and off with a red color and display only the last received data from my sensors without showing the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it with stat panel. You can add  'No value'  part 'device is off' and you can make the threshold red for off status.  For the part where it is on, you can set the threshold green.